# Forbidden 403 CSRF error when using request.post.get() method in views.py from html page

Tags: python, html, django, post, csrf

This is the views.py code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
# Create your views here.

def postdata(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data=request.POST.get('data')
return HttpResponse(data)`
```

this is the html code

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/minor/postdata/" method="POST">
data:<br>
  <input type="text" name="data"><br>


<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

i cant find the solution for request with post data from simple html page
i can get the code working for GET requests.
i need to connect this server from android app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are not sending the `csrf_token` with your post request. For security reasons, django checks csrf_tokens in all POST requests.

You can add csrf_token in your template using csrf_token templatetag, like this :

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/minor/postdata/" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
```

Read: [How to use CSRF token in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it)

Comment: Well, I am using simple html page....not template and calling the url directly from the page

Comment: If you are okay having a view that does not checks CSRF then use `csrf_except` decorator with your view. Else, you'll have to use JS to grab csrf cookie and then insert its value to the form.